Memory consumed by matplotlib freezes my machine completely
I'm working with ".nc" files that are pretty large (more than 2 G). The thing is, once i start trying to plot the graph (and it's not even a loop to produce different graphs) it becomes unresponsible.
When I plot a graph of a small ".nc", it goes all good and I already did some maps about Sea Surface Temperature. But I need to plot two components of the wind vectors ("U" and "V"). Even when trying with only one component (which should not print the vector, but at least show me if the pc can take it) the RAM goes up instantly and I have to shutdown VS Code before my system crashes.
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
#also "basemap-data-hires"


# file path, but i'm only using one component of the vector
data = Dataset('VV_850mb_2023.nc')
#extracting variables
lats = data.variables['latitude'][:]
lons = data.variables['longitude'][:]
time = data.variables['time'][:]
v = data.variables['v'][:]


mp = Basemap(projection = 'cyl', llcrnrlon= lons.min(), llcrnrlat= lats.min(), urcrnrlon= lons.max(), urcrnrlat= lats.max(), resolution='i')
lon, lat = np.meshgrid(lons, lats)
x, y = mp(lon, lat)
c_scheme = mp.pcolor(x, y, np.squeeze(v[0, :, :]), cmap='jet')
mp.drawcoastlines()
mp.drawstates()
mp.drawcountries()

cbar = mp.colorbar(c_scheme, location = 'right', pad = '10%')

plt.title('Wind Vectors above map')
plt.show()

I tried getting smaller components and files (it usually works), but once I go back to a larger file (even if it has less than 4 Gb) it freezes. I have a relatively powerful machine, so I don't think it has anything to do with hardware.

It would be useful to narrow down where the memory problem is occurring.  Without trying to plot, can you load the data without a problem?  If yes, can you plot it to an ordinary Matplotlib axes?

And try pcolormesh instead of pcolor

Thank you for the help. I'll try to look where it happened more closely, since i haven't treid to load data without plotting. Also try to pcolormesh once i get in the lab.
